# global name is not defined error for static method

Tags: python

For the code below I wrote for Binary Search Tree, I get the error delete_node(curr,value)
NameError: global name 'delete_node' is not defined. I am wondering why this will be the case for static method which is called from the instance method delete(self,value) . Why does it not work as a static method? I am calling it from a instance method 'delete' so does it does not require access to instance members explicitly.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.root = Node(value)
    @staticmethod
    def delete_node(node,value):
       if node is None:
           return node
       if value > node.value:
           node.right = delete_node(node.right,value)
       elif value < node.value:
           node.left = delete_node(node.left,value)
       else:
           if node.left is None and node.right is None:
               node = None
               return None
           elif node.left is None:
               temp = node.right
               node = None
               return temp
           elif node.right is None:
               temp = node.left
               node = None
               return temp
           else:
            #min_value = get_min(node.right)
               node.value = get_min(node.right)
               node.right = delete_node(node.right,node.value)

       def delete(self,value):
           if self.root == None:
           return
           curr = self.root
           delete_node(curr,value)
def get_min(node):
    curr = node
    while curr.left:
        curr = curr.left
    return curr.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = BST(5)
    tree.delete(5)
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: `BST.delete_node`

Comment: Sorry I had to correct the indentation. I was calling delete method which calls the delete_node method.

Answer (score 1):

The design of your class seems confusing.

In python, when we define a `staticmethod` that means the class name is just something like `namespace`, you can not access any member of the class in the staticmethod.

If you want `static` methods in C#, try [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod).

I recommend the [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod) for `classmethod` vs `staticmethod`.

In the specific question, change your code like this:

```
class BST:
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def delete_node(node,value):
    ...
               node.right = BST.delete_node(node.right,node.value)

    def delete(self,value):
        ...
        BST.delete_node(curr,value)
```

Comment: What about helper functions that you want to call from inside instance methods ?

Comment: But why does it not work as a staticfunction? I am calling it from a instance method delete.

Comment: @vkaul11, there are two different ways, replace all `delete_node` to `BST.delete_node`, or move the current `delete_node` function out of the class.

Answer (score 0):

As others have eluded to, in order to call methods on a class object you have to specify the thing you're calling it on.

So where you use `delete_node`, you can use `BST.delete_node` since it's static. The design is a bit odd given a BST would normally be done as an object encapsulated completely, but this is your immediate problem.

If it's an instance method, then you would call  `self.delete_node`

Comment: I wanted to use it as a helper function delete_node. How exactly do I accomplish that? Just make it an external method?

Comment: Yes, you can make it an external method / a free function if you wish to accomplish this.

Comment: But why does it not work as a staticfunction? I am calling it from a instance method delete.

Comment: A static function belongs to a class.  You can think of it as a helper function. For example, if you had the class "helpers" you could add things like "round" to it. It's a way of namespacing it. It lets you group things together instead of having 1000s of floating around functions

Comment: Yes but why does delete_node work as a helper function here ? I just put it inside the class as it is only useful within the class.